# Why does deref coercion not work with `From::from`?

Tags: rust, typeerror, dereference

From the [section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods) in the book:

> Deref coercion converts a reference to a type that implements the
> `Deref` trait into a reference to another type. It happens automatically
> when we pass a reference to a particular type’s value as an argument
> to a function or method that doesn’t match the parameter type in the
> function or method definition.

I'm trying to work out what's the difference between `bar` and `From::from` in the following code, meaning one compiles and the other doesn't.

```rust
struct T;
struct U;
struct W;

impl From<&U> for T {
    fn from(u: &U) -> T { T }
}

impl std::ops::Deref for W {
    type Target = U;
    fn deref(&self) -> &U {
       &U 
    }
}

fn foo(_: T) {}
fn bar(_: &U) {}

fn main() {
   let w = &W; 
   foo(T::from(w)); // error. "trait bound `T: From<&W>` not satisfied"
//   bar(w); // okay
}
```

I can get it to compile if I explicitly type `From::<&U>::from(w)`. But I didn't expect to have to. Even if there were multiple `From` implementations for `T`, a type can only `deref()` into one type so doesn't the compiler only have one option, try and deref the passed type and then see if the `From` implementation exists for the Target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `bar` is a concrete function while `T::from` isn't, it is one of any implementations of the trait. The compiler first has to find the correct implementation. But it finds that `From<&U>` is not implemented. Then it gives up.

There isn't even an attept at deref coercion going on here because none of the cases where the compiler would do so apply here.

We don't have a function yet ⇒ we don't have a target type ⇒ we can't "match the parameter type in the function or method definition".